Playwright check button is_disabled
I have a very simple test to check submit button is disabled or not. get the locator
The code is like:
`sub_button = page.get_by_role("button", name="Submit")

  expect(sub_button).to_be_disabled()`


And getting error :
E       AssertionError: Locator expected to be disabled
E       Actual value: False
Call log:
E       LocatorAssertions.to_be_disabled with timeout 5000ms
E         - waiting for get_by_role("button", name="Submit")
E         -   locator resolved to …
Can anyone help and give some ideas?
Thanks
Richard

tried to change the code to using locator, and method to check is_disabled, but none of them worked.


Please share a [mcve] with the full test and site under test. locator resolved to … is sort of important. I'd include the full error message. It's probably giving you multiple locator suggestions to use to disambiguate the locator with. Pick one of the options and code it in your test. Thanks.

Please show your "change the code to using locator" full code
